# Tradingview Pine script - top/bottom padding/spacing for custom indicator?

Tags: pine-script

I've seen that some custom indicators if not given appropriate height have plotshape objects that get partially covered by other panes. Is there a way to define padding space on the top or bottom of a pane to avoid this situation?